# How do I log errors from variables in a bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, scripting

I have a working script which goes out and checks what O/S the client is running and then runs the code relating to that which is checking the difference in NTP offset of the client against a master server.

I would like to add some error logging into this around the NTP commands but don't know where to start.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash


OS=`uname`

case $OS in
        [Linux]*)
Host=`hostname`
Offset=`ntpq -p | grep -e '*' | awk '{print $9}'`
Date=`date +%D`
CADate=`ntpdate -q 10.102.80.1 | awk '/nt/ {print $0}' | awk '{print $10}'`
TimeDiff=$(echo  $Offset - $CADate | bc )

#Output 
echo "$Host" "|" "$Date" "|" "$TimeDiff" > NTP.mif

        ;;
        [SunOS]*)
Host=`hostname`
Offset=`ntpq -p | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'`
Date=`date +%D`
CADate=`ntpdate -q 10.102.80.1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $10}'`
TimeDiff=$(echo $Offset - $CADate | bc)

#Output
echo "$Host" "|" "$Date" "|" "$TimeDiff" > NTP.mif
        ;;
        [AIX]*)
Host=`hostname -s`
Offset=`ntpq -p | grep -e '*' | awk '{print $9}'`
Date=`date +%D`
CADate=`ntpdate -q 10.102.80.1 | awk '/nt/ {print $0}' | awk '{print $10}'`
TimeDiff=$(echo  $Offset - $CADate | bc )

#Output
echo "$Host" "|"  "$Date" "|" "$TimeDiff" > NTP.mif
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Error logging in what sense? What is an 'error' in this context?

Comment: `Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.` Start with http://shellcheck.net

Comment: @AndrewDorsett : Good old `set -x` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to realise that there are two kinds of errors:

- You launch a UNIX/Linux command and this goes wrong.
- You launch a command and you see results you don't like.

In the first case, the error results go to the basic error stream, known as `1`. The errors can be catched and written to a logfile, like this (I use `>>` as I prefer to append to the logfile, not recreate from scratch):

```
command 1>>logfile_error.txt
```

For the second case, you have something like:

```
bad_result=$(command)
// check that the result is bad indeed
bad_result >>logfile_error.txt
```

(In this second case, the basic error stream is not immediately relevant)

Obviously, you can combine both:

```
bad_result=$(command 1>>logfile_error.txt)
...
bad_result >>logfile_error.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to output redirections you might want to conditionally decide what should be captured/printed out.
..so you might be interested in making a use of **return codes** given after executing a command which can be obtained by using **`$?`**

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html
https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html#FTN.AEN2981

just a usage example:
(not really a "good" one - rewritten in notepad without further testing, but still might be helpful for you - could be better)

```
#!/bin/bash

Host=`hostname`
OS=`uname`
ntp_ip=10.102.80.1
Date=`date +%D`

Offset_data=`ntpq -p`
Offset_rc=$? # you can a
if [[ $Offset_rc -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "Unable to.."
  #exit $Offset_rc # - uncomment if you don't want to continue 
                   #   with the script if your ntp command failed
fi

CADate_data=`ntpdate -q $ntp_ip`
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then # direct return code check
  echo "Unable to..,"
fi

case $OS in
        [Linux]*)
Offset=`echo $Offset_data | grep -e '*' | awk '{print $9}'`
CADate=`echo $CADate_data | awk '/nt/ {print $0}' | awk '{print $10}'`
        ;;
        [SunOS]*)
Offset=`echo $Offset_data | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'`
CADate=`echo $CADate_data | tail -1 | awk '{print $10}'`
        ;;
        [AIX]*)
Offset=`echo $Offset_data | grep -e '*' | awk '{print $9}'`
CADate=`echo $CADate_data | awk '/nt/ {print $0}' | awk '{print $10}'`
        ;;
esac

TimeDiff=$(echo $Offset - $CADate | bc )
#Output
echo "$Host" "|" "$Date" "|" "$TimeDiff" > NTP.mif
```